# Distinct value from ArrayList in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, list, distinct

I have the following ArrayLists:    1) `List<MAP<String,String>>` in 2) `ArrayList<>()` :

```
[
[{name=a,age=33,city=NY},{name=b,age=23,city=NY},{name=d,age=83,city=CA}],
[{name=f,age=53,city=FL}],
[{name=d,age=11,city=TX},{name=a,age=13,city=CA}],
]
```

I want to get new ArrayList with distinct values of names as:

```
[{a},{b},{d},{f}]
```

Can you assist :)?

Comment: You are talking about arrays but then say it is an `ArrayList`. What is it now? An `ArrayList` has nothing to do with arrays. It is a `List` which internally uses some arrays. Arrays are fixed-length structures, `List`s are way more dynamic and flexible.

Comment: you say MAP<String,String> , but which is the key & which is the value and how you fit in List , I am doesn't get it ????

Comment: ArrayList2.get(0).get("name") = a

Answer (score 1):

You can Iterate through your collection and add it to a Hash set to get Unique names.

```
List<Map<String,String>> input = new ArrayList<>();
    Set <String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<>();
    for( Map<String, String> stringStringMap : input )
        uniqueNames.add(stringStringMap.get("name"));
```

Or In Java8 this can be done in one line using stream

```
  Set<String> uniqueNames = input.stream().map(a -> a.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

And then you can use set to create an ArrayList(as you mentioned ArrayList in question ).

Comment: I didn't get it.
can you explain it again with full example? let say the name of the ArrayList of the example in the question is "Arr1"

Comment: @eyal1506 : traverse through the arraylist Arr1 . for each element in it do element.get(0).get("name") and add the result to a set. Your set is now a unique list of names. Convert this set to a list.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 you can do

```
//List<Map<String, String>> inList = new ArrayList<>(); 

List<String> outList = inList.stream().map(m -> m.get("name")).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```